# Which fruits loses less vitamins during a juice preparing?

Tags: micronutrients, fruits, nutrition, vitamin-c, juice

Some time I go to shopping and drink a juice, but I would like to know which one loses less vitamins during the preparation. Because I want to ask the juice that I can take more vitamins (it's expensive).

I already listened that vitamin C is one that need to be consumed fast, because it's fruit loses it fast. And about the others?